# Error in htmlInputElement Left hand side of an arithmatic operation must be of type any, num

Tags: angular, typescript

It works if I dont multiply the slider.value with 600 but I have to, to calculate the prices.
Error: number not assignable to string.

Ts file

```
var slider = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myRange"));
            var output = document.getElementById("p_price"); 
            output.innerHTML = slider.value;
            slider.oninput = ()=> {
            output.innerHTML = slider.value * 600;
            }
```

html

```
<input type="range" value="1" min="0" max="500" step="0" id="myRange">
<figure><span>$</span><b id="p_price"></b><i>/month</i></figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
       var slider = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myRange"));
        var output = document.getElementById("p_price"); 
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;
        slider.oninput = ()=> {
        output.innerHTML = ''+slider.value * 600;
        }
```